# What's the asymptotic distribution of $\exp(X_n)$, if $X_n$ is a sequence of asymptotically normally distributed random variables?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, asymptotics, lognormal-distribution, delta-method

Let $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}} $ be a sequence of asymptotically normally distributed random variables, such that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{n}X_n\sim N(0,1)$. What's the asymptotic distribution of $e^{X_n}$? 
I assume that $e^{X_n}$ is asymptotically lognormally distributed, because if we use the continuous mapping theorem with $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}X_n\overset{d}{=} X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ (since $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}} $ is a sequence of asymptotically normally distributed random variables), we get
$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}e^{X_n}\overset{d}{=} e^X\sim LN(\mu,\sigma^2)$. But how do I determine $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ ? My idea was to argue with the $\delta$-method,i.e. $e^{X_n}\overset{Taylor}{=}e^\mu + e^{\mu}(X_n-\mu)$ and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{X_n-\mu}{\sigma_n}\sim N(0,1)\Rightarrow \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{e^{X_n}-e^\mu}{e^{\mu}\sigma_n}\sim N(0,1)$. If we denote $\sigma_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ we get $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{n}X_n=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{X_n-\mu}{\sigma_n} $ for $\mu = 0$. But what is $\sigma^2$?. Slutsky's theorem for $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{n}X_n\sim N(0,1)$ implies that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} X_n\sim N(0,0)$, which would mean that $e^{X_n}$ is asymptotically distributed like the constant 1.

Comment: Since $X_n$ shrinks in some sense (depending on your meaning of "$\lim$") to *zero,* why are you interested at all in $\exp(X_n),$ which will be shrinking towards $\exp(0)=1$? It would be more worthwhile to analyze $\exp(\sqrt{n}X_n).$

Comment: True, but unfortunately that's not the exercise. If we were interested in $exp(\sqrt{n}X_n)$, we could simply use the continuous mapping theorem and see that $exp(\sqrt{n}X_n)$ is asymptotically lognormally distributed, i.e. $exp(\sqrt{n}X_n)\sim LN(0,1)$

Comment: In your formulation, isn't it immediate (and obvious) that $\sigma^2=0$?

Comment: This is the part which I don't understand, because $\sigma^2 = 0$ shouldn't be allowed. So I'd like to know where I made a mistake.

Comment: On what basis is $\sigma^2=0$ "not allowed"?  There's no mathematical problem with it and it provides a perfectly well defined distribution.

Comment: You are right, mathematically $\sigma^2=0$ is unproblematic. My problem with that solution is, that we normally assume $\sigma^2>0$, because otherwise $X_n$ would not be random asymptotically, but deterministic. So as a convention we normally say that for any normally distributed random variable $Y\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, that $\mu\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\sigma^2>0$ holds. That's why assume that I made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: Reading the second line of your post, I understand that $X_n$ is standardized and so has no unknown parameters. So how do the parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ suddanly appear?

Comment: I have found my mistake. You are quite right, the assumption that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} X_n\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2) $ is wrong, that was a missunderstanding on my part. What is right, is that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \sqrt{n} X_n\sim N(0,1) $ . If we use the $\delta$-method, we get $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \sqrt{n} \frac{e^{X_n}-1}{1}\sim N(0,1) $, which implies that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}  e^{X_n}\sim N(1,0) $, i.e. $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}  e^{X_n}\overset{d}{=}1$